# Terminate and run again program after text out

Tags: shell-script, shell

There is a bash that produces similar string "tokio-runtime-worker". The bash does not die further. It is required at the output of "tokio-runtime-worker" to terminate bash and run it again (cycle).

thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:

Comment: I think you should fix your Rust code

Answer (score 0):

You could do (in `zsh` or A&T ksh or `bash -O lastpipe`):

```
while
  sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec cmd 2>&1' | {
    IFS= read -r pid &&
      grep -q tokio-runtime-worker
  }
do
  kill -s PIPE "$pid"
done
```

(where `cmd` is the command that you want to restart when it outputs `tokio-runtime-worker`).

In other shells, that would not necessarily work as some run the last part of a pipeline in a subshell, the `$pid` would not be set in the main shell process. You could however do:

```
while
  sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec cmd 2>&1' | {
    IFS= read -r pid &&
      grep -q tokio-runtime-worker &&
        { kill -s PIPE "$pid" || true; }
  }
do
  continue
done
```

Where the `kill` (where we use the value of `$pid`) is run in the same subshell where the `pid` variable is set (by `read`).